# How to check for new documents in a different collection for security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

So in realtime DB, I could check for new data to be written in various paths via `newData().parent().parent()...parent()` in the security rules when I'm doing fanout writes.

e.g.

```
const fanout = {
  'users/user_a': {
    username: 'foobar'
  },

  'usernames': {
    'foobar': 'user_a'
  }
};

firebase.update(fanout);
```

And a security something like this:

```
"rules": {
  "users": {
    $user_id: {
      "username": {
        ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().parent().child('usernames').child(newData.val()).val() == auth.uid;
      }
    }
  },

  "usernames": {
    "$username": {
      ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().child('users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val() == $username"
    }
  }
}
```

If was wondering if there's a way to do this in Firestore's security rules? I've seen the `exists()` function but it's only for the existing documents, not something that's about to be written.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't currently an equivalent ability in Cloud Firestore Rules. You can use `request.resource.data` to examine the data being written in a request, but a batch write is treated as separate requests in Rules and there's no way to examine the net effect of all the writes like `newData` did in the Realtime Database. We're looking at adding this to Cloud Firestore in the future though.

If it's helpful, this specific use case could perhaps be solved without fanout, since you could do a `usersRef.where('username', '==' 'foobar').get()` query to get the user with a particular username.

Comment: I'd like to avoid that as having 2 separate transactions to save user and username could potentially cause data quality issues (e.g. what if the second transaction never gets saved because the user suddenly loses internet or closes the app). 90% of my writes are batches because of these exact same reasons. As a workaround, all those writes live in Cloud Functions which isn't ideal for me. I hope that feature lands in Cloud Firestore soon! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I explained really poorly. I meant to say that you could avoid fanout by getting rid of the "usernames" collection and just querying "users" directly, thus avoiding the need to write to two different places and use 2 transactions.

Comment: But how do I make sure that usernames should be unique per user? I don't plan on making it as the key since we want to make usernames changeable.

Comment: Ah! That's a good point. I've recorded your feedback and we'll try to bring similar functionality to Cloud Firestore in the future.